# Tornado url regex

Tags: python, regex, url, tornado

I want to get a domain name of a website (such as "www.google.com") as a parameter passing to the handler `app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/(\w+)", IndexHandler)]`.

When I run my test file, it failed because "www.google.com" does not match pattern `(\w+)`.

What I know about `(\w+)` is that it can represent a string of characters. I don't even know whether `(\w+)` is called Tornado url regex or not, but I want to know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\w` represents [word characters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

equivelant to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @V3ss0n the python documentation explains how it can match unicode characters: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: If request URL with Unicode characters to be handle , unicode flag will always needed , right? Will it be slower?